# Using Bluetooth to transfer data between two Pi's

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3b+, node.js

I am using two Pi 3B+'s, one is a calculator without a screen, the other one is the human interface with a screen.

I would like to command the calculator with the other Pi via Bluetooth.
I am using Node.js and I tried with Noble and Bleno but I don't understand how it works.

Is there a simple way to send/receive data between the two Pi's with Bluetooth?